# Equilibrium of a Solid Body

Tags: forces, torque, equilibrium

To find the torques around B, see the figure below, I took the cross product as followed:
[image]

and we know that **$W=160 N$** but when I insert that value into the the equation in the red box, I get **$F_3=46.2 N$** but they get **138.6 N**, how do they get that? the only possible way that can happen is if they multiply **$F_3$** by **3**.
[image]

Comment: Since the system is free to move in a fixed plane, you just need to be concerned with $F_{x}$, $F_{y}$ and $\tau_{z}$ assuming the drawing is in $x-y$ plane. By choosing a correct pivot point, you can get rid of some unknown forces in the first place using rotational equilibrium and then proceed with the translational equilibrium.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then it is what I already did. I talked about this with one of the T.A. and he got the same results as me, even thought he didn't use the crossproduct method. Our conclusion was/is, that they made an error in their calculations. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is wrong and you are correct.

$$\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{L}{2} \cos 60° \\ \frac{L}{2} \sin 60° \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -W \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -L \cos 60° \\ L \sin 60° \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} F_3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ W \frac{L}{2} \cos 60° - F_3 L \sin 60° =0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ F_3 = \frac{W}{2} \frac{\cos 60°}{\sin 60°} =  \frac{80}{\sqrt{3}} = 46.1880 $$